# Worklight: How to handle Push subscription on a Shared device

Tags: push-notification, device, ibm-mobilefirst, multi-user

I want to know what is the best approach to handle Push subscription for multiple users on a single/shared device?

In worklight, when another person is using the same device and subscribing for Push then it removes previous user subscription for the same device.

my App is a financial App and possibility is that family members may use the same device, that's why we have to take care of all scenarios

Any idea, or workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a device/OS limitation...

In iOS there is no multi-user support, so there is nothing one can do about it.
In Android, starting v4.2, there is multi-user support and there should be no issues (it will work out-of-the-box).

Edit: in native this is possible by creating your own user maintenance system. In Worklight, this is not doable at this time.

Comment: Okay its clear, can you please suggest best approach in such cases? Like, should it un-subscribe old user? or do not allow new user to subscribe? And what people normally do in such cases. Thanks

Comment: I don't think people normally share their phones. It is not a common use case. You shouldn't not-allow for another user to subscribe, because it might as well be the same user who decided to create a new account for whatever reason (and no longer use the previous one...).

Comment: You are right, but my App is a financial App and possibility is that family members may use the same device, that's why we have to take care of all scenarios. thanks